# Некорректно передаются числа в массиве при json_encode

Tags: php, json

Есть PHP-скрипт, который передает результат вычисления в массив. 
Например `$a[] = 2750*1.1`

Затем я делаю

```
$out['numbers'] = $a;
echo json_encode($out,JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION);
```

Проблема в том, что на сервере с PHP 5.6 результат получается целым (в данном примере 3025), а на PHP 7.1 результат с дробной частью (3025.000000000005). Хотя параметр JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION должен устранять эту проблему, этого не происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точно должно устранять? :)

> JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK (integer)
>       Кодирование строк, содержащих числа, как числа. Доступно с PHP 5.3.3.

Если нужна целая часть, то

```
$a = floor(2750*1.1);
```

Если округлить, то

```
$a = round(2750*1.1);
```

Если округлить в большую сторону

```
$a = ceil(2750*1.1);
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, допустил ошибку в описании. Параметр JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION всё таки. Увы, некоторые числа он выдаёт например 3849,9999999999995 вместо 3850. Так что округление - не выход.

Comment: @DenisI это проблема не php и не json_encode - это проблема дробных чисел. Округляйте принудительно до необходимой точности после запятой.

Comment: @DenisI Проблема для примера: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0699f886f1d97cda81c4dd07c9f09c96ed5e0897

Comment: $a = round(2750*1.1);
Простое округление помогло, спасибо.